# Excel VBA filter, deleting data & updating

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please help with my code, I am not a million miles away from what I am looking to do but I have now come unstuck and reached a dead end. I have no programming experience & am no expert with VBA so what I have done might not make sense, or look silly; please bear with me as I am learning.

What I want to do is be able to:

1. Filter Column H in sheet “master” to select dates before a date
   which I will input  in Range “B9”.
2. Delete the filtered  lines
3. Go to sheet “update”
4. Copy from A:18 dynamically to last column & last row
5. Paste everything in the last row in sheet “master”

Problem I have is that the filter for the date is not working

```
Sub AUTODATE()

Dim dDate As Date
Dim dbDate As Double
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
dbDate = DateSerial(Year(dbDate), Month(dbDate), Day(dbDate) + 1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("master").Select

If IsDate(Range("B9")) Then

dbDate = Range("B9")
dbDate = DateSerial(Year(dbDate), Month(dbDate), Day(dbDate)) + _
 TimeSerial(Hour(dbDate), Minute(dbDate), Second(dbDate))
        Range("H11").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Range("$11:$11").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & dbDate
        Range("$12:12").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells _
        (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            Range("A11").Select
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
               Sheets("update").Select
               ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
               Range("$18:$18").Select
               Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
               Selection.Copy
           Sheets("master").Select
           Range("A" & lastRow).Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial
    End If
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting dbDate to be? you aren't setting any value to it so it will be 0 and you aren't using the Date variable dDate

Comment: Try this alternative Range("$11:$11").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(dbDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(dbDate)

Answer (score 0):

The codes a bit messy near the bottom, and some thing's I'd normally push out to a separate function (find last cell for example).

```
Sub AutoDate()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastUpdateRow As Long
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim rFilterRange As Range

    Set wrksht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master")

    'Any statement that starts with a '.' applies to wrksht (With... End With)
    With wrksht
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'The range to be filtered - currently columns A:J (columns 1 - 10)
        Set rFilterRange = .Range(.Cells(11, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 10))

        'Turn off the autofilter if it's already on.
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
              wrksht.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        'Apply filter to correct range.
        rFilterRange.AutoFilter

        If IsDate(.Range("B9")) Then
            'Apply filter.
            rFilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & .Range("B9")
            If .FilterMode Then
                'Resize to ignore header row & delete visible rows.
                rFilterRange.Offset(1).Resize(rFilterRange.Rows.Count - 1) _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                .ShowAllData
            End If

            'Find new last row.
            lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Set rFilterRange = .Range(.Cells(11, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 10))

            lastUpdateRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            rFilterRange.Offset(1).Resize(rFilterRange.Rows.Count - 1).Copy _
                Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update").Cells(lastUpdateRow, 1)

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you are assuming that if the `AutoFilter` is `ON` the `FilterRange` is the range `rFilterRange` that is not a good assumption, you should clear the `AutoFilter` and Set it for the `rFilterRange`...

Comment: True - there's nothing stopping another range having a filter applied and the code will just assume it's the correct range.  I'll update my code.

Comment: After the update suggested by EEM I've now realised - if the filter returns no rows then `rFilterRange.Offset(1).Resize(rFilterRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp` will give error 1004 - no cells found.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**

1. Filter Column H in sheet `master` to select dates before a date located in same sheet at `B9`
2. Delete filtered lines
3. Copy from sheet `update` range `A:18` *dynamically to last column & last row*
4. Paste range from previous point in the *last row + 1* of sheet `master`

**Assumptions:** *(in line with code posted)*:

1. Data range in sheet `master` starts at `A11` and all cells in columns 8 of the data range have same `NumberFormat`
2. Data range in sheet `update` starts at `A18`
3. Data ranges in both sheets are continuous *(i.e. no blank rows nor blank columns in between)*
4. Copy of the data includes formulas & formats

*Thy this code:*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rng_AutoFilter_Delete_And_Paste()
Dim WshMaster As Worksheet, WshUpdate As Worksheet
Dim rMaster As Range, rUpdate As Range
Dim dDate As Date
Dim rTmp As Range

    Rem Application Settings - OFF
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Rem Set Worksheet Object - End Procedure If any of them is not present
    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error GoTo ExitTkn
        Set WshMaster = .Sheets("master")
        Set WshUpdate = .Sheets("update")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If IsDate(WshMaster.Range("B9")) Then

        Rem Cleared Records in Wsh Master
        With WshMaster
            Rem Set Date to Filter By
            dDate = .Range("B9")

            Rem Set Data Ramge in Wsh Master
            'Assumes range start at `A11` and it's continuous (i.e. no blank rows nor blank columns in between)
            Set rMaster = .Range("A11").CurrentRegion

            Rem Set AutoFilter
            'Use the `AutoFilter` property instead of the `AutoFilterMode` property
            If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
            rMaster.AutoFilter
        End With

        With rMaster
            Rem Filter and Delete Records in Wsh Master
            'Uses the `NumberFormat` to build the Filter Criteria
            'Assumes all cells in has same `NumberFormat`
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & Format(dDate, .Cells(2, 8).NumberFormat)
            'Sets a Temp Range to grab the Filter results
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rTmp = .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If Temp Range is `Nothing` then there is `Nothing` to delete
            If Not (rTmp Is Nothing) Then rTmp.EntireRow.Delete
            .Worksheet.ShowAllData
        End With

        Rem Set Data Range in Wsh Update
        With WshUpdate

            Rem Set Data Range in Wsh Update
            'Assumes range start at `A18` and it's continuous (i.e. no blank rows nor blank columns in between)
            Set rUpdate = .Range("A18").CurrentRegion

            Rem Set AutoFilter
            If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
            rUpdate.AutoFilter
        End With

        Rem Paste Records from Wsh Update into Wsh Master
        rUpdate.Copy
        'In line with code posted this assumes OP wants to copy the data as it is (i.e. including formulas & format)
        rMaster.Offset(rMaster.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Goto WshMaster.Cells(1), 1

    End If

ExitTkn:
    Rem Application Settings - ON
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html), [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html),

[Worksheet.AutoFilter Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff823161.aspx), [Worksheet.AutoFilterMode Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff821903.aspx),

[Worksheet Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

I have also done a review of your code see below *(including only lines with comments)*:

```
'lastRow variable is not declared.
'Suggest to always have Option Explicit at the begining of the module
'To do it goto Main Menu \ Options \ Tab: Editor \ Check: Require Variable Declaration
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'This is done too early as it will change after deletion of filtered rows

dbDate = DateSerial(Year(dbDate), Month(dbDate), Day(dbDate) + 1)   'Have no purpose as no value have been assigned to the variable as yet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'this should be done at the beginning

Sheets("master").Select 'should be qualified

dbDate = DateSerial(Year(dbDate), Month(dbDate), Day(dbDate)) + _
    TimeSerial(Hour(dbDate), Minute(dbDate), Second(dbDate))    'This line achieves nothing.

Range("H11").Select 'Select should be avoided, instead work with objects

Selection.AutoFilter    'Sould check first is the AutoFilter is ON

Range("$11:$11").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & dbDate   'Should filter the entire range

On Error Resume Next    'On error should be used for specific purposes and cleared after with On Error Goto 0

Selection.PasteSpecial   'After paste the Clipboard must be cleared with Application.CutCopyMode = False
```